# Show next question when next button is clicked

Tags: java, swing, file, jframe

I trying to read file in java. When click next button, how can I show second question when next button is clicked?

My `.txt` file content is like this

```
1. What is his name
A.John
B.David

2. How old is him?
A.24
B.27
```

So far I am able to display the first question in `JTextField`.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;


public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame
     */
    public NewJFrame() throws IOException {
        initComponents();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        pack();
        File file = new File("/home/xxx/Desktop/englishQuestion.txt");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append("\n");
                if (line.equals("")) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
        String result = sb.toString();
        jTextArea1.setText(result);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        textField1 = new java.awt.TextField();
        label1 = new java.awt.Label();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("Next");

        textField1.setName("\"\""); // NOI18N
        textField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                textField1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        label1.setText("Answer:");

        jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea1.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(label1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(textField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 53, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 57, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(28, 28, 28))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 421, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 206, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(label1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(textField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        label1.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("Answer: ");

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void textField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                          

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    private java.awt.Label label1;
    private java.awt.TextField textField1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactored the file lines to be like this:

> ```
> q1 = What is his name? | John | David
> q2 = How old is him? | 24 | 27
> ```

This way, each question information is in a single line and is easier to parse. You just have to load it as a property file and the q1 and q2 would be the keys, and what is after `=` would be the values. After that, split it by `|` or whatever you decide to use.

I refactored your code to look like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Properties props = new Properties();
    private List<Question> questionList = new ArrayList<>();
    private int currentQuestionIndex = -1;

    private class Question {
        private String question;
        private String answer1;
        private String answer2;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Question [question=" + question + ", answer1=" + answer1 + ", answer2=" + answer2 + "]";
        }

        public Question(String question, String answer1, String answer2) {
            this.question = question;
            this.answer1 = answer1;
            this.answer2 = answer2;
        }

        public String getQuestion() {
            return question;
        }

        public String getAnswer1() {
            return answer1;
        }

        public String getAnswer2() {
            return answer2;
        }

    }

    public void showNextQuestion() {
        currentQuestionIndex++;
        if (currentQuestionIndex >= questionList.size()) {
            jTextArea1.setText("No more questions available.");
            return;
        }
        jTextArea1.setText("");
        Question currentQuestion = questionList.get(currentQuestionIndex);
        String newLine = "\n";
        jTextArea1.append(currentQuestion.getQuestion() + newLine);
        jTextArea1.append("A. " + currentQuestion.getAnswer1() + newLine);
        jTextArea1.append("B. " + currentQuestion.getAnswer2());
    }

    public NewJFrame() throws IOException {
        initComponents();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        pack();

        Path path = Paths.get("/home/xxx/Desktop/englishQuestion.txt");
        props.load(Files.newInputStream(path));

        props.forEach((key, value) -> {
            String v = (String) value;
            System.out.println(v);
            String[] token = v.split("\\|");
            String question = token[0];
            String answer1 = token[1];
            String answer2 = token[2];
            Question q = new Question(question, answer1, answer2);
            questionList.add(q);
        });

        showNextQuestion();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        textField1 = new java.awt.TextField();
        label1 = new java.awt.Label();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("Next");

        jButton1.addActionListener(e -> {
            showNextQuestion();
        });

        textField1.setName("\"\""); // NOI18N
        textField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                textField1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        label1.setText("Answer:");

        jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea1.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING,
                        layout.createSequentialGroup().addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(label1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(textField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 53,
                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 57,
                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(28, 28, 28))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 421,
                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)));
        layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(
                javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING,
                layout.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 206,
                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                .addComponent(label1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(textField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30,
                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jButton1))
                        .addContainerGap()));

        label1.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("Answer: ");

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void textField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     *            the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code
        // (optional) ">
        /*
         * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default
         * look and feel. For details see
         * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        // </editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    private java.awt.Label label1;
    private java.awt.TextField textField1;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

Notice that I used a Properties object to load all the keys, and then for each of those lines, I parsed it and created a Question object and add it to a questionList. Also, notice the `jButton1.addActionListener(e -> { showNextQuestion(); });`. Call showNextQuestion(); method everytime you want the next question, in this case, every time to click the Next button.

I'm not sure what you want to acomplish with this application, is not clear yet, but I simply answered your question on how to show the next question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your questions in the file should be in uniform format, I mean we should be able to distinguish between different question and it's options.

Secondly, then you read each question and it's options and store it in an Java Object. Let's say **Question** object.

Question object might be something like below:-

```
class Question {
   String questionString;
   String[] options;
}
```

Then, after you read each question/options and form an Object, you store these objects in a ***DoublyLinkedList***, so you can easily navigate back and forth when user clicks *Previous* button or *Next* button.